# How to prevent text inside of xml element from being encoded?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm having a little trouble with encoding in my C# application.

So, what I'm trying to do is take an xml element and stuff some data inside of it so I can transport that data through a file to another application. However, whenever I go to serialize that element, the xml text inside of the element is encoded. Is there any way to prevent it from being encoded?

So an example of what something I could have is like this:

```
<element attribute="foo">
    <![CDATA[ some data here.... ]]>
</element>
```

But what it actually outputs is this:

```
<element attribute="foo">
    &lt![CDATA[ some data here.... ]] &gt
</element>
```

Here is my serializer:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer( objToSerialize.GetType() );
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent = true
};

using ( StringWriter writer = new StringWriter( xml ) )
using ( XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create( writer, settings ) )
{
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add( "", "" ); // Removes the xsd & xsi namespace declarations from the xml
    serializer.Serialize( xmlWriter, objToSerialize, ns );
}

return xml.ToString()
```

How can I prevent this from occurring? Thank you!

Comment: If you are generating XML why would you want to prevent encoding? That is to keep the XML valid, at the other end you just need to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're generating your XML in a `StringBuilder`, the `XmlWriter` doesn't check for CData sections automatically. You'll have to generate the xml manually using the `XmlWriter` methods, like `WriteCData` or using another framework, such as Linq to Xml.